# Can someone please explain this Java line simply?

Tags: java

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
```

Honestly, the entire g2 and g concept is confusing. Can anyone explain it? Thanks.

Additionally, an explanation of the difference between g and g2 would be nice.

Comment: Please add the line on which g is declared as without that it's difficult to explain what the cast is doing.

Answer (score 4):

Presumably, `g` is a `Graphics` instance, `Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;` is casting `g` to an instance of `Graphics2D`.

This is an example of [Polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) in action...

Around Java 1.3/1.4 the new [`Graphics2D` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) was introduced into the Java API, but because most of the paint methods required `Graphics`, they weren't updated (for backwards compatibility).  The developers however basically guaranteed that any system generated `Graphics` passed to these paint methods would get an instance of a `Graphics2D` context

Basically, `Graphics2D` is an extension to the `Graphics` API

Have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Comment: So can I always use Graphics and g in place of Graphics2D and g2?

Comment: That would depend on what you were trying to achieve.  `Graphics2D` adds a bunch new (and handy) features, if you're not using them, then yes, you can continue using an instance of `Graphics`...

Answer (score 0):

You cast a `Graphics` object called `g` in `Graphics2d`.

It is an example of [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29).

Basically the graphics 2d extends the graphics class in awt.
Graphics itself is an abstract class, so it can't be created, it only defines some interface and some functionality.

Maybe the oracle API could help you:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html